# How to activate Aux on Japanese Honda Fit 2009 Gathers VXH-093 cvi?

Tags: honda, audio, fit

How to activate Aux on Japanese Honda Fit 2009 Gathers VXH-093 cvi? I bought an IP-BUS aux cable, and I don't know how to activate aux on Gathers VXH-093 cvi.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be found [on this pdf](http://www.honda.co.jp/manual-access/navi/vxh-093cvi/pdf/vxh-093cvi-a-05.pdf). The problem is its in Japanese and I cannot read it. I cannot find an *easy* way to convert a pdf from Japanese to English. If you (or someone online) can do this, I'm sure you'll find your answer. If it's not there, I pulled it from [this page](http://www.honda.co.jp/manual-access/navi/vxh-093cvi/) where there are load of pdf's for your system.